How to detect clear icon press in ios keyboard in flutter?
This code is working for laptop keyboard delete key press. But it's not printing backspace pressed in iphone and android clear icon pressed . How to achieve this?
Enter the first three digits of the 4-digit PIN incorrectly.
Press the X button on the keyboard to clear the previous field.
Observe that the focus remains on the current field (PIN), even after pressing the X button multiple times, preventing the user from easily correcting the mobile number
Pressing the X button should move the focus to the previous field and clear it, allowing the user to re-enter the correct information.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class OTPPinWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int length;
  final bool isPassword;
  final Function(String)? onComplete;
  final double height;
  final double width;
  final double spaceBetween;
  final double borderRadius;
  final double borderWidth;
  final Color borderColor;
  final Color fillColor;
  final MainAxisAlignment mainAxisAlignment;
  final bool isError;

  const OTPPinWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.length,
    required this.isPassword,
    this.onComplete,
    this.height = 54,
    this.width = 54,
    this.spaceBetween = 16,
    this.borderRadius = 8,
    this.borderWidth = 1,
    this.borderColor = Colors.black,
    this.fillColor = Colors.transparent,
    this.mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    this.isError = false,
  });

  @override
  _OTPPinWidgetState createState() => _OTPPinWidgetState();
}

class _OTPPinWidgetState extends State<OTPPinWidget> {
  late List<TextEditingController> _controllers;
  late List<FocusNode> _focusNodes;
  final FocusNode _keyboardFocusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controllers = List.generate(widget.length, (_) => TextEditingController());
    _focusNodes = List.generate(widget.length, (_) => FocusNode());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (var controller in _controllers) {
      controller.dispose();
    }
    for (var focusNode in _focusNodes) {
      focusNode.dispose();
    }
    _keyboardFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void clearTextFields() {
    for (var controller in _controllers) {
      controller.clear();
    }
  }

  void handleBackspace() {
    for (int i = widget.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (_focusNodes[i].hasFocus) {
        if (_controllers[i].text.isEmpty && i > 0) {
          _focusNodes[i - 1].requestFocus();
          _controllers[i - 1].clear();
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.isError) {
      clearTextFields();
    }

    return Focus(
      focusNode: _keyboardFocusNode,
      onKeyEvent: (FocusNode node, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event is KeyDownEvent) {
          if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace ||
              event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.clear) {
            print('Backspace pressed');
            handleBackspace();
            return KeyEventResult.handled;
          }
        }
        return KeyEventResult.ignored;
      },
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: widget.mainAxisAlignment,
        children: List.generate(widget.length, (index) {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                  width: widget.borderWidth, color: widget.borderColor),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.borderRadius),
            ),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: widget.width,
              height: widget.height,
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _controllers[index],
                focusNode: _focusNodes[index],
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                obscureText: widget.isPassword,
                obscuringCharacter: '●',
                maxLength: 1,
                textInputAction: index == widget.length - 1
                    ? TextInputAction.done
                    : TextInputAction.next,
                inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]'))
                ],
                onChanged: (value) {
                  if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                    if (index < widget.length - 1) {
                      FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                    } else {
                      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                    }
                    final otp = _controllers
                        .map((controller) => controller.text)
                        .join();
                    if (widget.onComplete != null) {
                      widget.onComplete!(otp);
                    }
                  }
                },
                onTap: () {
                  _controllers[index].selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                    TextPosition(offset: _controllers[index].text.length),
                  );
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                      start: 4, top: widget.isPassword ? 36 : 24),
                  counter: const SizedBox.shrink(),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.borderRadius),
                    borderSide:
                        const BorderSide(width: 0, color: Colors.transparent),
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.borderRadius),
                    borderSide:
                        const BorderSide(width: 0, color: Colors.transparent),
                  ),
                  fillColor: widget.fillColor,
                  filled: true,
                  isDense: true,
                  counterText: '',
                ),
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: const Color(0xFF221F1F),
                  fontSize: widget.isPassword ? 12 : 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

        if (event is KeyDownEvent) {
          if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace ||
              event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.clear) {
            print('Backspace pressed');
            handleBackspace();
            return KeyEventResult.handled;
          }
        } ```
    This print log is not
 printing on clicking clear button in keyboard in ios

